# Heroku won't serve Ember/Rails app resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ember.js

I have built a basic CRM app to learn Ember. The app uses a Rails back end; and Ember and Rails communicate with a JSON api. Feel free to check out the [source code on my GitHub](https://github.com/adam-wanninger/ember-crm-js). The app is hosted [here.](https://ember-rails-crm.herokuapp.com/)

The app works great in my development environment, and deploys to Heroku with no issues whatsoever.

However, when I navigate to the apps URL I see a blank page. Further inspection using Chrome's dev tools tells me that none of my javascript files were sent from Heroku to my browser. What gives?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to add the rails_12factor gem to my Gemfile. It looks like for any Rails/Ember app to work correctly on Heroku, this gem is required.

As per Heroku:

> Heroku integration has previously relied on using the Rails plugin
>   system, which has been removed from Rails 4. To enable features such
>   as static asset serving and logging on Heroku please add
>   rails_12factor gem to your Gemfile.